# Multiple locations (longitude,latitude) in theme

Tags: theming, location

I have to put multiple gmap markers in a map. The catch is... The location field is in the theme itself (longitude,latitude) no gmap module. I tried to enter 2 values separated by a comma but it doesn't work. I'm not very good with PHP but i have this in theme-settings.php:

// Cocoon Map Settings: Latitude

```
$form['cocoon_options']['cocoon_map_settings']['map_latitude'] = array(
    '#type'          => 'textfield',
    '#title'         => t('Map Latitude'),
    '#default_value' => theme_get_setting('map_latitude'),
    '#description'   => t("Latitude for the map address."),
  );
```

// Cocoon Map Settings: Longitude

```
 $form['cocoon_options']['cocoon_map_settings']['map_longitude'] = array(
    '#type'          => 'textfield',
    '#title'         => t('Map Longitude'),
    '#default_value' => theme_get_setting('map_longitude'),
    '#description'   => t("Longitude for the map address."),
  );
```

And this part in the page--front.tpl.php:

```
<?php if (theme_get_setting('show_map')): ?>
        <div id="map-canvas" data-lat="<?php print (theme_get_setting('map_latitude')); ?>" data-lng="<?php print (theme_get_setting('map_longitude')); ?>" data-zoom="10" data-style="style-2">
        </div>
        <div class="addresses-block">
            <a data-lat="<?php print (theme_get_setting('map_latitude')); ?>" data-lng="<?php print (theme_get_setting('map_longitude')); ?>" data-string="<?php print (theme_get_setting('map_marker_text')); ?>"></a>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Can someone help me with this one?
Thanks!

Comment: try leaflet module

Comment: if you are using geolocation or geofield module into the field of your content go to managefield->your_map_field->edit->change Number of values ->unlimited